# Solicito cordialmente solucion a esto

Tags: bash, pseudocódigo

#puede sonar ridiculo pero ya hice de todo y pues necesito ayuda con un pequeño script en #bash. el caso es que necesito #concatenar en orden unos strings y las envio en 2 #parametros y debo unirlos como el ejemplo que esta aqui:

```
#!/bin/bash
v1="${1}"
v2="${2}"
uno="UMREP113"
v3="${uno}${1}-${2}"

echo "$v3"
```

#los valores de vi= "20230402" y v2="20230405" y necesito imprimir esto:"el valor del #archivo es: UMREP11320230401-20230405"#
#ME SALE TODO ENRREDADO ME IMPRIME ASI:30405 DEL ARCHIVO ES:UMREP113.#
#ayuda por favor es urgente. gracias y disculpen mi ignorancia querida comunidad.

Comment: Por favor, lee [ask]. En lugar de colocar en el título que necesitás ayuda (lo cual es sabido, ¡por eso redactás una pregunta!), pon el problema _específico_ que estás teniendo. Títulos así _espantan_ a usuarios que probablemente puedan ayudarte.

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que entiendo, deseas concatenar los valores de las variables $v1 y $v2 junto con la cadena "UMREP113", y luego imprimir el resultado de forma específica, puedes corregir el script de la siguiente manera:

```
v3="${uno}${v1}-${v2}"
```

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y describe cómo este código responde a esta pregunta. No es que "pruebe" y ya: ¿cómo alguien podría entender tu respuesta sin contexto? Lee [answer].

Comment: Hola 3RR0R404, gracias por colaborar, podrías editar tu respuesta y agregar el texto que completa la misma, ("**El valor del, etc**"), así quedaría correcta y evitarías los votos negativos.